# Vertex snapping does not work in the same object

Tags: snapping

I am new to blender but not to 3D modelling in general. I am having a strange problem regarding with vertex snapping.

I have several objects in my scene. I am trying to translate one vertex to another location with transform tool. I would like to do it in one axis (preferebly Y axis). The problem is that, the vertex that I am trying to relocate doesn't snap to the other vertices in the same object. If I try to snap it to vertices of a different object, it does snap.

I attached a video that demonstrates this. I am also attaching the blend file for it. Could you please help me figure out what the issue is or provide a work around?

Screen Recording:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yf6soj9Kj8tVHbvwIm_9ZaxLr7-3Xx48/view?usp=sharing

Blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FTdDkCF6oEYSz_bBtCRi5ZrFfOODTwXj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Most likely this is because proportional editing is on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have proportional editing enabled. Snapping to self does not work with it.

[image]

Comment: Okay. Could you show me how can I disable it? I am kinda new to blender and I have no idea what am I doing sometimes :)

Comment: I just added a GIF. Hopefully that helps.